# can anyone help me with this error?

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-settings

```
./trimmomatic-0.36.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
./trimmomatic-0.36.jar: line 2: $'\bi\203uH': command not found
./trimmomatic-0.36.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\a\217\245\234D\312\017\265\026\234\311{\234T\315.\204\024\266ת\353\2179\343\354\003PK\003\004''
./trimmomatic-0.36.jar: line 3:h�uH��\��META-INF/MANIFEST.MFM�=� w���GSS�V;7.ƕ�ҧ�h��{�����F��N����R<    ���>��~A�$��-U�ِ    +�������i�}M���i@�F���;������zC�K�X]�L�=g#�(���D����{�T�.��ת��9��PK'
```

Comment: Looks like you tried to run `./trimmomatic.jar` instead of `java ./trimmomatic.jar`.

Answer (score -1):

These are character encoding errors. The jar file was built with assumption about character set that are not true in the system where you are trying to run it. All of that backslash stuff is your system's way of showing characters it does not understand